# Overload += operator to add unique_ptr to std::list C++

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading, move-semantics, unique-ptr

Suppose I have an abstract base class `vehicle`, and two derived classes `car` and `truck`. I have a third class `dealership` that contains a list of `car` and `truck` instances. `dealership` contains a private data member `list<unique_ptr<vehicle>> vehicleList`.

Suppose I create an instance of `dealership` as `dealership d1("bobsCars");` and an instance of `car` as `unique_ptr<vehicle> c1(new car("Toyota", 1988, 1500));`

**How do I overload the += operator so that I can do `d1 += std::move(c1);` to move `c1` to `d1`?**

I tried overloading the += as a member function of `dealership` as follows,

```
void operator+=(std::unique_ptr<vehicle> v){
  vehicleList.push_back(std::move(*v));
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
void operator+=(std::unique_ptr<T> v){
  vehicleList.push_back(std::move(*v));
}
```

But I get an error `error C2664: 'cannot convert argument 1 from..`

I can get this to work with raw pointers by changing the list to `list<vehicle*> vehicleList`. Creating a car instance as `vehicle* c1 = new car("Toyota", 1988, 1500);`

```
void Task::operator+=(vehicle* s){
  vehicleList.push_back(s);
}
```

Creating a `dealership` instance as `dealership d1("bobsCars");`, and adding a new car to `vehicleList` by,

`d1 += std::move(c1);`

What am I missing? How do I convert the raw pointer version to a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Actual code and actual errors.  Minimal code however, but code that compiles and generates the error you don't understand.  [MCVE]

Comment: `std::move(*v)` should be `std::move(v)` because you are trying to move the pointer, not the thing it points to.

Comment: @immibis Thank you! std::move(v) worked. I was positive I tried it before posting this.